# Оператор is и кортежи

Tags: python, python-3.x, операторы, tuple

Возник вопрос, почему происходит именно так:

```py
>>> (1, 2) is (1, 2)
False
>>> () is ()
True
```

Ведь, кортеж - это неизменяемый тип данных, и два одинаковых кортежа должны быть одним объектом в оперативной памяти.

Так например:

```py
>>> 1 is 1
True
>>> 'str' is 'str'
True
```

Comment: > два одинаковых кортежа должны быть одним объектом в оперативной памяти. С чего бы это?

Comment: А почему 2 одинаковых кортежа должны быть одним объектом?  Неизменяемость объекта еще не гарантирует, что объект с такими же атрибутами будет тем же самым объектом. Иначе приходилось бы при создании каждого кортежа проверять, а не создан ли уже еще одни с такими же параметрами

Comment: @Viktorov но, ведь в примере с int и string это работает.

Comment: @freak-js пример с `int` - это особенность реализации CPython, сделанная для ускорения его работы. Она будет работать не всегда и не везде. Рассчитывать на такое поведение не стоит.

Comment: Как-то так: 'is' != '=='

Comment: В общем то ответ на ваш вопрос довольно просто. При создании кортежа интерпритатор не проверяет, что такой уже не создан, а просто создает его. В общем говоря документация такого и не обещает. Да и нет в этом необходимости, т.к. кортежи прекрасно сравниваются на равенство.

Comment: кортежи - неизменяемые типы данных, которые могут содержать ссылки на изменяемые типы данных. именно поэтому два "одинаковых" кортежа не идентичны.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Самое главное:*

> Два одинаковых объекта не обязаны иметь одинаковый адрес в памяти, но
>   это возможно. В Python 3.7, благодаря [новой оптимизации AST](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7ea143ae795a9fd57eaccf490d316bdc13ee9065), иногда так и происходит, в версиях ниже - нет. Полагаться на это поведение ни в коем случае нельзя.

### Теперь подробнее...

Для начала стоит сказать, что это зависит от конкретной версии Python (*точнее CPython*).

***Python 3.7:***

```py
print((1, 2) is (1, 2))  # True
```

***Python 3.6:***

```py
print((1, 2) is (1, 2))  # False
```

---

Для того, чтобы понять некоторые различия в версиях, предлагаю дизассемблировать этот код.

**Начнём со старой версии (*3.6*):**

```py
print(dis.dis('(1, 2) is (1, 2)'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((1, 2))
              2 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
              4 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

4-ая колонка с числами (`2, 3, 8`) - это `opargs` (аргументы операции). Обратите внимание на то, что команда одна и та же (`LOAD_CONST`), данные одни и те же (`(1, 2)`), но эти данные являются ***разными аргументами*** при операции.

Следовательно, они будут разными объектами в памяти (*но я немного сомневаюсь насчёт этого утверждения*)

Давайте взглянем на список констант скомпилированного кода, чтобы точно в этом убедиться:

```py
code = compile('(1, 2) is (1, 2)', '<string>', 'single')
print(code.co_consts)
(1, 2, None, (1, 2), (1, 2))
```

Кортеж `(1, 2)` встречается 2 раза, то есть это разные объекты.

---

**Новая версия (*3.7*):**

```py
print(dis.dis('(1, 2) is (1, 2)'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              4 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Уже на этом этапе видно, что наш кортеж является одним и тем же аргументом в операции.

Подтвердим наши догадки, взглянув на константы:

```py
code = compile('(1, 2) is (1, 2)', '<string>', 'single')
print(code.co_consts)
((1, 2), None)
```

Как видим, объект один, поэтому и адрес в памяти один.

Результат в новой версии отличается из-за перемещения некоторых оптимизаций байт-кода в новый оптимизатор AST.

*Выдержка из [нововведений](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#optimizations):*

> Constant folding has been moved from the peephole optimizer to the new
>   AST optimizer, which is able perform optimizations more consistently.
>   (Contributed by Eugene Toder and INADA Naoki in [bpo-29469](https://bugs.python.org/issue29469) and
>   [bpo-11549](https://bugs.python.org/issue11549).)

Поэтому скомпилированный код очень сильно отличается от интерактивного сеанса:

*Интерактивный режим:*

```py
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> y = (1, 2)
>>> print(x is y)
False
>>> print((3, 4) is (3, 4))
True
```

*Скомпилированная версия:*

```py
x = (1, 2)
y = (1, 2)
print(x is y)            # True
print((3, 4) is (3, 4))  # True
```

Подобные оптимизации касаются также других объектов.

---

Также в разных версиях отличается результат следующих инструкций:

```py
x, y = 257, 257
x is y
-6 is -6
```

### Давние особенности

Тестирую *Python 3.7* в интерактивном режиме.

Сначала немного примеров:
*№1:*

```py
>>> x = 257
>>> y = 257
>>> x is y
False
```

*№2:*

```py
>>> x = 256
>>> y = 256
>>> x is y
True
```

*№3:*

```py
>>> x = -6
>>> y = -6
>>> x is y
False
```

*№4:*

```py
>>> x = -5
>>> y = -5
>>> x is y
True
```

*№5*

```py
>>> x = 'Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit'
>>> y = 'Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit'
>>> x is y
True
```

*№6*

```py
>>> x = 'Hi!'
>>> y = 'Hi!'
>>> x is y
False
```

Из этих примеров видно, что Python ***кэширует числа в промежутке [-5; 256]***.
[*Пруф*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/long.html?highlight=pylong_#c.PyLong_FromLong)
Также он ***кэширует простые строки***.
[*Пруф*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/unicode.html?highlight=internfrom#c.PyUnicode_InternFromString)

Но если запускать скомпилированный код, то в *Python 3.7* все примеры вернут `True`.

---

На основании примеров выше, хочу предупредить, что ***сравнивать любые данные оператором `is` ни в коем случае нельзя***. Используйте для этого только оператор `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор is используется для проверки того, указывают ли сравниваемые переменные на один и тот же объект в памяти. Пустые кортежи, вероятно, указывают на NULL или же нечто подобное, потому идентичны.
Два заполненных кортежа – самостоятельные объекты в памяти. Это то же самое, что объявить две переменных в C++ и сравнить их адреса. Очевидно, что результат будет разным. Вы говорили:

> кортеж - это неизменяемый тип данных и два одинаковых кортежа должны быть одним объектом в оперативной памяти

однако в этом высказывании первое утверждение отнюдь не влечёт второе. Вернитесь к аналогии с переменными C++, приведённой выше, если причина всё ещё не понятна.