# Как отключить кэширование маленьких объектов Python?

Tags: python, кэширование

Классический пример:

```py
a = 5
b = 5
print(a is b)
```

Выводит `True`. Марк Лутц говорит, что Python кэширует маленькие значения и потому так происходит.

Вопрос: как отключить кэширование, чтобы при создании каждой новой переменной создавался физически новый объект с уникальным ID?

Comment: Так-то кешируется немного чисел -- от -5 до 256: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4830f581af57dd305c02c1fd72299ecb5b090eca/Objects/longobject.c#L18-L23 А отключение кеширования это необходимость или любопытство? :) просто непонятно зачем оно вам нужно :)

Comment: @gil9red Было бы очень удобно отличать две переменные с одинаковым значением друг от друга. В С есть, по крайней мере, адреса, хочется чтобы ID были чем-то подобным для Python

Comment: Если того требует логика программы, то можно просто написать свой класс-обертку для целочисленных значений.

Comment: 1) можно попробовать вещественные `a = 5.0` (но это просто костыль) 2) или [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) 3) сделать свою реализацию чисел

Comment: @mkkik Это понятно. Но вопрос не в том, как это реализовать обходным путём, а в том, как отключить кэширование.

Comment: Отключение кэширования не предусмотрено разработчиками даже на этапе компиляции интерпретатора. Необходимо вносить правки в реализацию целых чисел.

Comment: Это очень сильно зависит от версии и реализации. Если в кратце, то отключить кэширование нельзя. Советую прочитать мой ответ из этого вопроса: [Оператор is и кортежи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003018/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-is-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не советовал заниматься подобным "хакерством". Если вам нужно зауникалить объекты, и при этом не расходовать память, а писать свои класс не хочется, то есть простое решение - кортежи:

```
myvar = 5
a = (myvar,)
b = (myvar,)
print (a is b)
print(id(a)==id(b))

# False
# False
```