# Фокусы с is и int в python

Tags: python

**Начнём с str.**

*"Следите за руками":*

```
>>> a = 'ab'
>>> b = a
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True
>>> c = 'a'
>>> d = 'b'
>>> b = ''
>>> b = c + d
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

Пока всё предсказуемо.

**Но вот чего смущает:**

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>>
>>> c = 3
>>> d = 2
>>> b = 0
>>> b = c - d
>>> a is b
True  # Опля!
>>> a == b
True
```

Отчего сие, господа?
Почему именно **int** работает по другому?

Comment: Числа от -5 до 256 кэшируются питоном, чтоб много объектов не плодить

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4830f581af57dd305c02c1fd72299ecb5b090eca/Objects/longobject.c#L18-L23

Comment: В английской версии огромный ответ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Comment: Я как-то отвечал про это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003018/Оператор-is-и-кортежи/1003195#1003195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и сказал @andreymal переменные в питоне кэшируются(по моему не только числа).
Это делается чтобы не загромождать пространство.
Можно провести экспeремент со скоростями с кэшом и без.
Отключите его  [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300126/disable-caching-for-python).

Comment: На сколько мне известно, кэш вообще может очень по разному работать в командной строке и в "исходнике". Байт код более оптимален. Особенно начиная с python 3.7! Например то чего у меня выше  в str примере - в байт коде по другому должно сработать на python 3.7+

Comment: Может быть ,не очень шарю в кэше питона :)