# 42 одинаков для разных ссылок!

Tags: python

Как известно, объекты обладают `identity` и `value`. Для сравнение на первое используется `is`, на второе - `==`. Но почему тогда результаты отличаются в следующем примере?

```
>>> x = 1000
>>> y = 1000
>>> x is y
False        # ожидаемо

>>> x = 42
>>> y = 42
>>> x is y
True         # почему???
```

Comment: Из-за кэшей питона.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662398/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-python-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-ida-idb-id1)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003195/339283